# 50$ per day requirement for entry into Turkey

Tags: turkey, e-visas

I am travelling to Turkey in ten days on an already approved e-Visa. The visa document says that, I need to prove that I hold a return ticket, hotel reservation
and at least 50 $ per each day of my stay.

My questions:

1. Hotel reservation: I am staying in Turkey for 8 days, out of which I have hotel reservation only for 4 days. For the rest of the days, I am hiking. Do I really need to show hotel reservation for all 8 days?
2. 50$ per day proof: How do I show that proof? In cash?

Comment: Not sure they really check that thoroughly…

Comment: Never seen the passport control in Istanbul checking or even asking.

Answer (score 6):

I got a reply from Turkish embassy for my question. I will post it here verbatim:

> You should comply with all the requirements stated in the e-visa
>   site. You can at least show your hotel reservations + hiking tour
>   documents. You can show some cash + credit cards + bank statement.

My take on it is that these requirements sound pretty lax but you should try to take as many supporting documents as you can.

Comment: Update: The immigration officer didn't ask me to show any kind of documents except my e-visa and my schengen residence permit.

Answer (score 3):

We arrived in Istanbul last month from the UK and I was not asked to prove this $50 requirement, nor was I even aware of it. My passport was stamped in a few seconds and that was that.

I guess it depends on where you are travelling from. If you are coming from the West, I would imagine they think you're going to be able to support yourself. If you're coming from a poor country then they might think you're there to look for work. That might be unfortunate but that's the way of the world.

Comment: Thanks. I am from India. I was in Istanbul one and half years ago when they didn't have e-visa facility and got visa on arrival since I have schengen residence permit. At that time, they didn't ask me anything. It's highly likely they won't ask me anything this time too. But I want to be prepared, just in case.

Comment: It's not an East/West thing, more like a legit explanation they'll quote not to let you into the country if they suspect your main purpose is to go begging on the street.